# How can I stop UIScrollView calling drawRect: on sublayers that go in/out of the visible region?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, animation

I've got an animation that is a bit laggy, and I've narrowed it down to this:

As part of the animation, a `UIScrollView` is auto scrolled. Even though the subviews appear to be loaded, if they are outside the scroll views bounds, then `drawRect:` will be called on these views as they are animated back into the visible region (I'm implementing my own `drawRect:` on each of these views). This is what's making my animation stutter.

I've got shouldRasterize set to true for each of the scroll view's subviews, no difference. How can I force `UIScrollView` to keep each of the views in memory even if goes out of the scroll view's bounds?

Comment: Are you implementing your own draw rect on these views that you are scrolling into the scene?

Comment: @jackslash yea, sorry should have said that.

Comment: Do the views change their content much?

Comment: @jackslash they're kind of like buttons, they highlight when you tap on them - that's about it. The draw rect code is quite expensive because they're rather good looking buttons :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your drawing code out of draw rect and into some other method. 
Instead of rendering into the context for the view render into an image context. Add this method to the start of your drawing code to make an image context:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
   CGSize size,
   BOOL opaque,
   CGFloat scale
);
```

Use it like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
   self.bounds.size,
   NO,       //if you are doing rounded corners or anything, else YES
   0.0       //Scales automatically for retina displays
);

//Need a reference to the context you just made?
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Your CG drawing code works as normal. Then render the context to an image

```
UIImage * renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Dont forget to

```
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Call this drawing code from somewhere that will draw only once needed. These are some candidates for methods you can override:

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview //called when adding to a view
- (void)layoutSubviews  //called when first displayed, on frame change and after setNeedsLayout has been called.
```

Then set those images on the view. If you have buttons, you should have subclassed UIButton. You can now `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` Et voila, performace!

Comment: This is brilliant! I'm having a wee problem implementing it though - everything works except that everything is now drawn in grayscale. It's the same no matter where I call it from, although if I try to use the image method in drawRect: nothing draws. Also, the darker something should be, the lower it's alpha level - so everything ranges from dark and mostly see through to pretty solid white. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Ahh, found this about the layer using the debugger: [<CGColorSpace 0x834f7d0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray)] Any idea how to change this?

Comment: Aha, changed CGContextSetFillColor(context,CGColorGetComponents([buttonColor CGColor])) to CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,[buttonColor CGColor]). Now all is working fine, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going at this the wrong way. Instead of having UIScrollView tell its subviews to either draw or not is not the way to go. Apple did fix this issue with UITableViews, by creating a queueing system. Enqueue a subview if none is already available for reuse.

I wrote my own collection view about a year ago and that's the path I had to go down. It also saves on memory, as you are reusing subviews as opposed to creating new ones.

I understand it's a lot more involved, but it'll definitely solve your problem.

Check out this code from Apple, they use something similar.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080

Comment: Thanks, good point. My scroll view is a small and finite length though, so if it's possible to just store everything once and not worry about queuing I'd much rather do that - will keep this idea in mind though! Also, after doing some more tests it seems that if only part of the view was visible before, it still calls drawRect: on the other part. So even if the view was all queued up, then (I could be wrong) but would it have to call drawRect: still?